# I can't get res.status.json message in alert

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I was trying to get res.status.json as an alert, but what I could only get was this;

[image: result]

this is my Server join.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('../mongoose/index');
const router = express.Router();
const Customer = require("../mongoose/schemas/customers");
const crypto = require('crypto');

mongoose.connect();

router.get("/", function(req, res, ) {
  fs.readFile("./views/join.html", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send("error");
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
      });
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    }
  });
});

//Check duplicated id
router.post('/duplicated', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      userid
    } = req.body;
    const existingUser = await Customer.findOne({
      userid
    });

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.json({
        exists: true
      });
    } else {
      return res.json({
        exists: false
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Server Error'
    });
  }
});

// Registeration
router.post("/", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      userid,
      userpw
    } = req.body;

    const hashedPassword = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(userpw).digest('hex');

    const newCustomer = new Customer({
      userid,
      userpw: hashedPassword
    });
    await newCustomer.save();


    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Join Completed'
    });
    //res.status(201).redirect("/login");

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Server Error"
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is my client join.js

```
const userid = document.querySelector("#userid"),
  userpw = document.querySelector("#userpw"),
  userpwc = document.querySelector("#userpwc"),
  matchMessage = document.getElementById('password-match-message'),
  registrationButton = document.querySelector("#SignupButton"),
  idCheck = document.querySelector("#idcheck"),
  userIdWarning = document.querySelector("#userIdWarning");


userpwc.addEventListener('input', confirmpw);
idCheck.addEventListener("click", checkDuplicateID);

//Registration
async function register() {

  const newUserId = userid.value;
  const newPassword = userpw.value;
  const newPasswordc = userpwc.value;

  try {
    // 회원가입 요청
    const response = await fetch('/join', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userid: newUserId,
        userpw: newPassword
      })
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.message);
    if (data.message === 'Join Completed') {
      alert(data.message);
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "/login";
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      // if join failed
      console.error('Login Failed:', data.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}

// check pw
function confirmpw() {
  let value1 = userpw.value;
  let value2 = userpwc.value;

  if (value2 !== "") {
    if (value1 === value2) {
      matchMessage.textContent = "Match";
      matchMessage.style.color = "#4caf50";
    } else {
      matchMessage.textContent = "Doesn't Match";
      matchMessage.style.color = "#f44336";
    }
  } else {
    matchMessage.textContent = "";
  };
}

function checkDuplicateID() {
  const newUserId = userid.value;
  const regexs = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}$/;


  if (!newUserId) {
    idCheck.innerText = "Type your id";
    return;
  }

  if (!regexs.test(newUserId)) {
    idCheck.innerText = "Invalid id";
    return;
  }

  // check duplicated id
  fetch('/join/duplicated', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userid: newUserId
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const userIdWarning = document.getElementById('userIdWarning');
      // if duplicated
      if (data.exists) {
        userIdWarning.innerText = "Unavailable ID";
        registrationButton.disabled = true;
      } else {
        userIdWarning.innerText = "Available ID";
        // not duplicated
        registrationButton.disabled = false;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

plus, I could make endpoint of fetch('/join/duplicated', by the way, it was impossible to make endpoint of /join/register. When I tried to Post registeration by fetch('/join/register', and then console printed POST join/404

[image: Console]

Thank you.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof data)` show?

Comment: I think you should be getting the alert, since you're not getting any of the error messages. Have you tried setting breakpoints in the code so you can step through it and look at the variables?

Comment: This definitely looks like a failure to prevent a default form submit event action. What triggers your client-side functions to execute? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant HTML.